# How to get a history of incoming and outgoing transactions for a certain address?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, bitcoind, bitcoin-core

Along with the history of incoming and outgoing transactions, how would I find the first block that that address appeared in (to find when the wallet was created)? 
I want to do this by parsing with bitcoin abe or something along those lines. 
I'm not the programmer, but I need to know how to tell the developer what I'm looking to create.

Answer (score 2):

To get the history of incoming and outgoing transactions all you need to do is send "listreceivedbyaddress" command to the bitcoind rpc interface. For more detail see here. 
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list

To see where the address first appeared is more intense, you will need to run a search query on a block chain and analyze each block up until you find an appearance.

Answer (score 0):

To get a history of incoming and outgoing transactions for a address you will need to  parse the blockchain.

The command `listreceivedbyaddress` only shows that the input of one address does not display the output.